# refreshing the browser overwrites the child's content in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am a complete beginner in the database world. I'm trying to use Firebase database and here is the problem I encounter: I want to create a simple signup where the user should write the info and this info should be stored in Realtime Database. That is to say, when the user enters his info and clicks on "sign up" user 1 should be created, then user 2 enters his info and user 2 should be created, but all of them must be same level "childs". Everything seemed to be working fine, I created an object (in Javascript) then I added to the database as a "child" named "user 1", but when I refreshed the page and entered other info for user 2, this info overwrote user 1's info, but when I just delete user 1's info from the input fields in the browser (without doing a refresh) and enter user 2's info it creates the second "child" named user 2 as it was supposed to be and it's what I want to be. The question is why refreshing the browser overwrites the previous info. Here is my js code:

```
function submitClick(x){
    var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
    user_number ++;
    firebaseRef.child("user" + " " + user_number).set(x);
}

function signup(){
    var first_name = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
    var last_name = document.getElementById("last_name").value;
    var username = document.getElementById("user_name").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var obj = {
        First_Name: first_name,
        Last_Name: last_name,
        Username: username,
        Password: password
    }
    return obj;
}

var hold;
var user_number = 0;
submit_btn.onclick = function() {hold = signup(); submitClick(hold)};
```

and the html is just input fields and a button named "sign up"

Answer (score 2):

When you reload your page, the JavaScript is reloaded and executed again from scratch. It has no memory of what happened before you reloaded it.

That means that this line executes again:

var user_number = 0;

And thus `user_number` starts counting from `0` again.

The simplest way to fix this problem is to use Firebase's `push()` method:

```
function submitClick(x){
    var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
    firebaseRef.push().set(x);
}
```

This generates a new unique ID under the root, where it sets the user. While these so-called push IDs are not as easily readable as your numbers, they are guaranteed to be unique across reloads, multiple users, and even offline/online conditions.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. One more question please. Can we say that firebaseRef.push() creates kind of an instance under root ref and then with set(x) we put the data under that instance?

Comment: Sort of... `push()` generates a reference to a new unique location. To learn more about it, see https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html and https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html